# Which event was used to call function

Tags: javascript, events, resize

How can I know in an an example like the below, which event was used to trigger the function?

```
function setSize() {
    if() { // event == 'load'
        console.log("Loaded");
    } else if() { // event == 'resize'
        console.log("Resized");
    }
}
window.addEventListener('load', setSize, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', setSize, false);
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can use event.type

Comment: `function setSize(e) { if(e.type === ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function setSize(event) {
   if(event.type == 'load') { // event == 'load'
        console.log("Loaded");
   } else if(event.type == 'resize') { // event == 'resize'
        console.log("Resized");
   }
}
```

<s>window.addEventListener('load', function() { setSize(event) }, false);</s>
<s>window.addEventListener('resize', function() { setSize(event) }, false);</s>

```
window.addEventListener('load', setSize, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', setSize, false);
```

Comment: You don't need to use an anonymous function like that. The way he had it was fine. He just needed to define the `event` parameter to `setSize`. The way you're doing it, it's expecting to find a global `window.event` object, which isn't available in all browsers.